# Failed to import the required Python library (ansible-pylibssh)

Tags: python, ssh, ansible, cisco-ios

I am experiencing an issue while running a simple `Ansible playbook` that checks for firewall rules on the `Cisco NX` side. My `Red Hat` system is in a disconnected environment, so I am manually installing packages.

**The error message:**

```
msg: Failed to import the required Python library (ansible-pylibssh) on devc-bitbckt-01's Python /usr/bin/python3.11. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter.
```

Please note that I haven't made any changes to the content of the error message, only corrected the surrounding grammar.

**My `ansible.cfg` file:**

```
[defaults]
remote_user = venom
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

[privilege_escalation]
#become = true
#become_method = sudo
#become_user = root
become_ask_pass = false
#ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.11

#[paramiko_connection]
#record_host_key=True
[persistent_connection]
ssh_type = libssh

[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
```

**My Host file:**

```
[routers]
172..x.x
#ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

[all:vars]


[routers:vars]
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_network_os=ios
#ansible_become=yes
#ansible_become_method=enable
#=
```

The venom user can `SSH` into the `Cisco Box` without a `SSH` password.

**My Playbook:**

```
---
 - name: Checking running cisco config
   hosts: routers
   vars:
     ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.11
   gather_facts: no
   connection: local
   tasks:
    - name: Verify ACL is present
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - sh access-l
        waitfor:
          - result[0] contains 'permit 172.x.x.x.'
```

**Which Command:**

```
which python
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin)
```

**I also have two versions of `Python`:**

```
[root@bitbckt-01 ~]# python3 --version
 Python 3.6.8
[root@bitbckt-01 ~]# python3.11 --version
 Python 3.11.2
```